# fail2ban for dovecot not working

Tags: dovecot, fail2ban, ufw

i have set up ufw in linux mint and works fine.

in my linux mint box i run dovecot and i see many failure login tries.

I set up fail2ban like this:

```ini
[dovecot-pop3imap]
enabled = true
filter = dovecot-pop3imap
action = iptables-multiport[name=dovecot-pop3imap, port="pop3,imap", protocol=tcp]
logpath = /var/log/
maxretry = 2
findtime = 1200
bantime = 1200
```

in /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/dovecot-pop2imap.conf i put this line:

```ini
[Definition]
failregex = (?: pop3-login|imap-login): .*(?:Authentication failure|Aborted login \(auth failed|Aborted login \(tried to use disabled|Disconnected \(auth failed|Aborted login \(\d+ authentication attempts).*rip=`<HOST>`
```

Failure login tries keep continue. Any suggestion?